# Boolean operator in if-statement acting funky

Tags: java

I've been sitting here trying to wrap my head around how this code runs.  I understand (or thought I understood) how boolean operators work in if-statements, but apparently I don't.  The code is:

```
public class Exercise_6_24 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;
        String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
          "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        // found indicates whether a suit has been picked
        boolean[] found = new boolean[4]; 

        // Count the number of picks
        int numberOfPicks = 0;

        // Count occurrence in each suit
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 4) {
          numberOfPicks++;
          int index = (int)(Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_CARDS);
          if (!found[index / 13]) {
            found[index / 13] = true;
            count++;

            String suit = suits[index / 13];
            String rank = ranks[index % 13];
            System.out.println(rank + " of " + suit);
          }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of picks: " + numberOfPicks);
      }
}
```

It's basically one of those card picking problems.  The part where I'm getting confused is the first if-statement in the while loop.  Prior to the loop, all the slots in the found boolean array is set to false.  Yet, the if-statement in the while loop is testing if the found boolean array is set to true, and if it is true, run the code in the if-statement.  It shouldn't run, but it does.  When I set a breakpoint there, I saw that the boolean array slot changes from false to true to make the code inside the if-statement run.

I seriously do not understand how this is happening.  Can someone explain to me how this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Did take the not (!) into account?

Comment: `!found[index / 13]` gives you true (! false) and inside the if statement you are doing `found[index / 13] = true;`  so which part you don't understand?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the kind of question that will get far on SO.  Try a Java-specific site list javaranch.com

Comment: @DarenW - There's nothing wrong with the question.  But the problem is a simple misreading of the logic, and is therefore of no real interest or help to anyone but the OP.  He has his answer ... lets move on.

Comment: I do want to say, BTW, this code is rather schizophrenic about magic numbers.  There's not much point to having a const `NUMBER_OF_CARDS` if you're just assuming it's 52.  (Dividing by 13 to get a suit only works if `NUMBER_OF_CARDS` is always 52, or if it's less and you remove cards a suit at a time.  More will trigger an exception when you try to mess with `found[4]` or `suits[4]`.)

Comment: I'd personally suggest using `ranks.length` rather than `13` and `suits.length` rather than `4`, and actually, calculating `NUMBER_OF_CARDS` as `ranks.length * suits.length`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not testing if it's true, you're testing if it's false. This statement:

```
!found[index / 13]
```

Means:

> Take the position of `found[]` at `index / 13`, and test if it is *not* `true`.

`!` is a Boolean complement, so it inverts the value. If `found[index / 13]` is `false`, then `!found[index / 13]` is `true`, so the `if` statement will run.

Answer (score 2):

`if (!found[index / 13]) {`

Read this as "If this card is **NOT** found". It is checking if the value is **`false`**, because only then would !found[..] be true, and the `if` block would execute.